# How many ways there are to open a room with ten doors?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A room has $10$ doors. I want to find the distinct possibilities to open this room.

My approach. For each door we have two distinct possibilities. Thus we have $2^{10}-1$ possibilities, bacause all doors may be opened. Is this approach correct?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly right. You have one way for every non-empty subset of the doors.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Please, if you do not mind, add your comment as an answer. I will accept it.

Comment: Done! $\qquad\,$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's exactly right. You have one way to open the room for each non-empty subset of the doors, and there are $2^{10}-1$ such subsets.